# NodeJS and synchrone call to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I m actually developping a little application, in which I use a service to access my data in MYSQL.

Actually, it works great using callback fonction :

```
service.request('SELECT * FROM table', function(data){
    mydata = data
})
```

I need to use it without callback, without blocking the node eventloop like this :

```
mydata = service.request('SELECT * FROM table')
```

Is it possible to do this ?
How could I do ?

EDIT : How to do this with Fiber and Future libraries ? :D

Thanks for advance

Comment: You either use a callback, or block the script execution. Your choice. Using `Promise`s may help you with your asynchronous code.

Comment: I dont know promises with node. Does it need a specific module ?

Comment: IIRC, for the current "stable" version of Node (1.10.x), yes. But promises *are* coming to Javascript and I think they *are* defined in node 1.11.x.

Comment: why "without callback"? And no, "without callback, without blocking the node eventloop" is not possible in node.

Comment: I needit to learn more about node and the eventloop system. What about a blocking solution ? I tried promises, but we told me that there is a better solution to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use wait.for, a wrapper over Fibers:

https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

```
var wait=require('wait.for');

function process(){
   var data = wait.forMethod(service,"request",'SELECT * FROM table');
   console.log(data);
}

wait.launchFiber(process);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the response from the server before you can continue code execution, then there is nothing you can do but wait for it to get back. This code should be written in the callback.

If you want to get the response from the server, but don't necessarily need the response to continue code execution, then you should write this code after making the call but outside of the callback.

```
service.request('SELECT * FROM table', function(data) {
    var mydata = data;

    //do the stuff that requires mydata
});

//keep doing stuff that does not require mydata.
```

The thing is, you can't both get your data back from the database and not wait for it to come back! No amount of technology can solve that problem :)

Comment: And how do I wait for this response, I accept blocking solution. :)

Comment: You wait by waiting for your callback to be called. This is the whole paradigm!

Comment: If you want to hack it, a `while(myData == null) {}` would probably do the trick.